# Doctrine2 Order By before Group By

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, subquery, doctrine-orm, dql

I am having issues implementing a sub-select solution for ORDERING a resulting dataset before the GROUP BY reduces it.

Normally, in SQL you would do a sub-select:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM a_table order by a_table.timestamp desc
) as table_tmp
group by userId
```

However, I am having difficulty implementing this in DQL.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

My query is more complex than this and I assume I JOIN other tables through 'table_tmp' and in the outer SELECT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid DQL isn't able to handle such a complex query. However Doctrine allows you to write a custom SQL query and map its results into objects.

Read more about native queries on [Doctrine's documentation pages](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html).