# Doctrine2 "order by" before "group by"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I know that similar question was asked 3 years ago ([Doctrine2 Order By before Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446762/doctrine2-order-by-before-group-by)) but maybe from that time something changed.

i have 2 entity propertes:

```
orderId
orderUpdateDate
```

both as a pair are set to be unique, but for listing I need last update date so sorting should be

```
order by orderUpdateDate DESC
```

and then grouped by orderId so I have orders only once.

```
group by orderId
```

problem is such that when I paste both in one query in query builder I got random listing of orders

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve such a result you'd have to end up with following *SQL* query:

```
SELECT n.id, n.update_date
FROM (
    SELECT o.id, o.update_date
    FROM orders o 
    ORDER BY o.update_date DESC
) n 
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Unfortunately Doctrine's DQL doesn't support nested queries in `FROM` clause. However, it allows you to create a custom, [native SQL query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) that can be mapped by ORM:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MyProject\\Order', 'o');

$sql = sprintf('SELECT %s FROM (SELECT ...) GROUP BY ...', $rsm->generateSelectClause());

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I had to add "ORDER BY n.update_date" to main query and this works great now. thank you for help very much.

Comment: is it someway possible to add to such query "count(n.id) as id_num" to have in results also number of order updates for every order? I tried and query is ok but have no idea how to use this value as symfony says that there is no method id_num